# Mosaic Aerial Photography Tiles to a Seamless Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic

I've got about 6 different Aerial Photography datasets I am managing at the moment. All of them are made up of tiles covering a large area. Some of these datasets contain up to 2000 tiles. All the tiles are slightly overlapping so there re no gaps in the data. Tiles work fine for me, but other users are requesting Mosaic's of the datasets.

I've been trying over the last few days to Mosaic these tiles into a seamless raster. I've been using the [ArcGIS Mosaic to New Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000098000000) Tool. It worked great on the first (smallest) dataset, but since then ArcGIS crashes after running for about 8 hours. I've tried the tool on a more power machine and with less tiles, but ArcGIS still keeps crashing.

I'm not sure what else to do here. I need to mosaic these tiles into one raster, but despite any changes to the options I keep getting the same result. I'm wondering if the Moasic to New Raster is the correct tool for this job, or should I be using something else?

I'm looking for a either a ArcGIS or python programming solution to this issue.

The options I am using for the Mosaic to New Raster Tool:

- Input: 500 to 2000 input tiles that are JP2
- Output: Save the new raster as a JP2
- Coordinate System: NAD83 17N to NAD83 17N
- Pixel Type: 8 Bit Unsigned to 8 Bit Unsigned
- Cellsize: 0.2 to 0.2 (varies, but the the cellsize stays the same from the input to the output)
- Band: 3 (4 in two dataets)
- Mosaic Method: I've tried pretty much every option here, the preferred is Blend.
- Colourmap: First (I haven't changed this at all yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend creating a [mosaic dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000037000000) within a file geodatabase.  There are many advantages of working with this type of data model.  For one, you can modify properties of the dataset once it is created to enhance rendering.  You also have much finer control of how these data are served compared to a stand-alone raster dataset created using mosaic to new raster.

*Additional Resources:*

- [What is a mosaic dataset?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_a_mosaic_dataset/009t00000037000000/)
- [Mosaic dataset properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Mosaic_dataset_properties/009t00000038000000/)
- [Creating a mosaic dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Creating_a_mosaic_dataset/009t0000003p000000/)
- [Adding raster data to a mosaic dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000003r000000)

Comment: It's worth a shot. I had used these in the past, but found the file sizes (when sharing over a network) where much larger than working with a Mosaic-ed JP2. I'll let you know how the process goes. In the meantime, if anyone has any other suggestions I all ears.

Comment: I agree the only option I did was performed this method when I had over 12,000 NGA imagery tiles and use this mosaic dataset toolbox and it works great. The only thing is you have to have the original local imagery or else you will get the black and white checkerboard.How big is it ? I tired to export it to jp2000 with no luck so I just l leave at it alone.

Comment: Worked fantastic! Took about 12 hours to load all the tiles in, but it's working great. I'm going to continue using the raster catalog and also try and mosaic the catalog to a JP2 as well.